# Input of 20~23v, need output of 24v

Tags: boost, step-up, 24v

I have a supply that outputs either 20v or 23v, I need to step that up so it is always a fixed 24v no matter what. How can I make sure it is always a fixed 24v?

Edit: This is for a coin hopper. It needs 24V with '2A start falling to 850ma when running'. The electronics feeding it only give 20V for a dollar and 23V for $5, which makes the coins come out very slow (I am not sure current, will have to check). When I hook the hopper up directly to a 24v power supply it runs at full speed, so I am hoping if I can always make sure it has a full 24v when active it will give coins faster. Run time is quick: seconds at max (I think 20 coins are given in 4 seconds)..

Comment: There is. But that's likely not what you wanted to ask. Can you edit and improve your question what kind of answer you expect?

Comment: Also, how much current does your application need from the 24 V supply?

Comment: And what is the load that requires "24 V no matter what"? Most 24 V systems such as found in commercial vehicles or industrial automation would work quite happily at 23 V.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a boost converter.

There are a large variety of pre-built power supplies, DC-DC converters, ICs, etc. that can be used to accomplish this.

If you just want to buy something that does the job for you, DC-DC boost converters are a solution:  [Examples](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-converters/132?s=N4IgjCBcoKwOwGYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2uABwAsMAnFSMWLfQ89VVWPZ6-QRgADP3o1aNMYjijiAJjAwEwmJ3kaEQ9RoBsWnXW7qEVREwUIGwpApryGcdfF331cGmBHuYu3WoU4HipdTl16XXk%2BYjgwXVVOejikxN9xfmEwUykWYXj5KQBdYgAHABcoEABlMoAnAEsAOwBzEABfFhpY5BA0SCw8IlIKcBgYENCFdiUnYhUYLosQKL9tKY9-Tg8YJU4zWKWqPQhieg8bRIQJaPBhMzdciToMmAcT8DiYYRuvM7BZ8A0UwXTr%2BOL8GhdFQQ8RXEDFEDlSo1BotdosV5qaC9DA4AjEMiQShKHZUJAIpGQap1JqtNr0oA)

If you want to add a boost converter to your own PCB, you can easily build your own using a boost controller IC.  The datasheets for these will show you what external components you need and how to calculate them.  [Examples](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/dc-dc-switching-controllers/715?s=N4IgTCBcDaIEYHsEGcAuACAxggdgNwFMAnVYkAXQF8g)

You can also take advantage of online tools such as [Texas Instrument's Web-Bench Tool](https://www.ti.com/tool/WEBENCH-CIRCUIT-DESIGNER), which will help you design whatever you need in this regard.  Specifically, look at the [POWERSTAGE-DESIGNER](https://www.ti.com/tool/POWERSTAGE-DESIGNER) tool within Web-Bench.